# New Q&A site model for time sensitive / too localized questions

Tags: discussion

This is an extension to an [earlier post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51843/self-delete-or-expire-time-sensitive-questions/51847#51847). It's shame that many questions can't be asked or get closed because they are too localized or time sensitive and the questions go nowhere, unless they are asked elsewhere on the web.

So if you have a question about a piece of hardware you're building for a computer, or a question about the Turkish version of Windows or an old version of an obscure piece of software, you're out of luck.. in the trilogy sites.

If the current model doesn't support these questions, why not create a new Q&A site which caters to these questions and serves as a bucket for them. Let it have its own model. Questions expire and automatically get deleted.

People know that's the way it works. I don't mind answering questions knowing my answers will not last forever.

While these questions' value erode over time, they are very valuable at the time of asking and that's what matters. The model is not about serving the bigger population, Google juice or longevity. Such a site can still bring in a lot of page views and make money from ads.

Personally I will find a lot of value for such a site.

**Addition:**

Process would be to **close** the question and **move** it to the other site, instead of just closing it which will kill the question.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you want to ask really time sensitive questions...

> When will Visual Studio 2010 be released?

Or geographically localized questions...

> Are there any Visual FoxPro user groups near Peoria, IL?

Or logically localized questions...

> Should I buy the Intel whoozit 43k extreme, or the AMD whoozit 4.3 Black edition?

This stuff is better done in a Twitter or [chat room type format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy), where the *expectation* is that the information is ephemeral and temporary -- though closer to "real time".

Comment: Twitter is an inefficient place to do this because the only way someone sees your question is if they did a search on a word you used in your tweet or both joined a related list and if there's no such list, you're out of luck. Tried Twitter, it didn't work. Even if someone knows the answer, it's unlikely they bother replying unless they have a vested interest.

Answer (score 1):

If "too localized" is being used for questions that actually *are* highly localized, then such a site will have very limited value by comparison to the existing SOFU sites and will see little participation, meaning that it won't work as well as the rest of the trilogy.

That is just the nature of highly local questions.

Comment: It's not a site trying to compete with the current sites. It's complimentary. A bucket for neglected, overcast, not allowed, closed, too whatever questions.

Comment: ...which no one will spend any time on....

Answer (score 0):

A rough overview of the process for proposing new Stack Exchange sites is listed on the  [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/518474918/stack-exchange-2-0).  Site proposals go [somewhere around meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=site-proposal&sort=newest&pagesize=15).

Comment: The idea is to start with the current users from the 3 sites instead of starting from scratch. I am not interested in taking up and maintaining such a site.

Comment: @Tony: So this is a "here's something I'd like *someone else* to do" kind of thing. I got it.

Comment: That 'Someone else' are the current sites owners. This process makes most sense when it's integrated with the current model. It can only be visible when question is closed.