# Are antagonistic viewpoints welcome on SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) is IMO very different from other SE sites, because its subject is religious, and thus very prone to antagonistic viewpoints (like [mine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/729/atheist?tab=reputation)). I obviously expected my opinion to be not welcome there:

[image]

But I've been noticing also that my comments are disappearing (the [post itself](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/will-atheists-go-to-hell-solely-on-that-basis) was also deleted). So, are antagonistic viewpoints welcome on SE sites like Christianity.SE?

Comment: Comments aren't expected to stick around

Comment: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/614/how-can-we-improve-our-guidance-about-the-comment-practices

Comment: @random I personally didn't see anything egregious in my comments, but I am not asking why the comments were deleted. That statement is there to support the question.

Comment: It's times like these that I pine for the good ol' "Subjective & Argumentative" close reason...

Comment: Of the two questions you had that received the most downvotes, one asked a question that was not backed by the information you cited, and the other was phrased in a way that insinuated that Christians are more gullible.  They were bad questions, plain and simple.

Comment: FWIW, I think that religious based sites should welcome opposing or non-conformist views, *as long as it leads to robust and measured discussion*. Anything just thrown in there as a troll should be eliminated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not a friend of organized religion, have nothing invested in Christianity.SE and probably never will, but what's the point of participating in a Christianity related site if you're an atheist?

It's like being fundamentally, totally opposed to every aspect of programming but still participating in Stack Overflow (or programmers.SE). It doesn't work.

As far as I'm concerned, unless one intends to contribute something truly *constructive*, one should not contribute to the religion sites at all.

Comment: Seems like a good way to learn about an unfamiliar religion.

Comment: [Preaching to the choir](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64/the-role-of-the-non-believer-on-the-site/84#84). Sites like Christianity.SE are a honeypot for this, though.

Answer (score 18):

### Writing on the wall

So you didn't *expect* your opinion to be welcome, *observed* that your opinion was not welcome, and you've now come here to ask *us* if your opinion is welcome?

Oh, what the hell. Yes, your *opinion* is welcome. Because SE sites *luuuuurve* opinions. There's even [a close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45740/rename-subjective-and-argumentative-close-reason-to-argumentative-inflammato/95187#95187) that mentions them, because we want them *so badly*. The more antagonistic, the better. Nothing we want more than some good ol' content-free flame-wars - this "useful Q&A" shtick just gets so *boring*!  Please, jump on the next new SE site you see and share some opinions.

Or, y'know, read the FAQs, note the response that posting flame-bait garners, and adjust your behavior accordingly.

Comment: @Null: you *could* argue that. But you didn't. In fact, your entire question could work pretty well as an *answer* to your question. I'm honestly not sure why you even bothered to ask; did you expect someone to say, "Yes, C.SE is *different* - unlike every other SE site, we want lots of arguments there".

Comment: That is kinda what I am asking. Do we?

Comment: No. Good grief man, if it devolved into that, we'd just kill it. After three years of telling folks that we don't want holy-wars and that SE is a poor fit for discussion, why would we build a site *purely for that purpose*? The closest we've ever come would be Programmers, and that was... "redirected" right quick if you'll recall...

Answer (score 4):

Your question is based on a flawed premise.

In the comments, random linked to a meta discussion for Christianity.SE that clearly spells out why comments are being deleted: it's not about you having antagonistic viewpoints, but about keeping the site clean of off-topic and tangential discussions.

You link to a screenshot of downvotes you've received: you have no proof that people are downvoting you because you have an antagonistic viewpoint. You could have just as easily been downvoted because people view your posts to be wrong or not useful. This isn't Reddit: merely having an opinion doesn't mean people should or will up-vote you.

It's easy to dismiss negative feedback as "oh these people are just trying to supress my viewpoints", but I guarantee you will find Stack Exchange more enriching and rewarding if you take the negative feedback you received, consider it given in good faith, and see how you can improve on what you've been doing.